# Rewrite Page with a slug before page name

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting

I am using $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules

I have the following code that works:

```
'name/(.*)' => 'index.php?post_type=post';
```

Im able to use a url like http://mysite.com/custom_name/post_name

using $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules, how can I make pages work the same way.

This is just an example:

```
'anothername/(.*)' => 'index.php?post_type=page'; //for all pages

'anothername/(.*)' => 'page/pagename' //for one specific page
```

Is there a way I can have a page look like this:

```
 http://mysite/custom_name/page_name.
```

The two examples above just redirects me to:

```
http://mysite/page_name  //without the slug
```

Comment: is there a reason why you're using non wp rules and not adding them to the internal rewrites?

Comment: I need it to be masked, and still be able to access the url I'm reference to.

Comment: are you not using pretty permalinks? that's what the internal rewrites do if you've enabled pretty permalinks.

Comment: Yes, im using pretty permalinks, i have no problem rewriting for posts, just on pages. In posts I can do so something like sitedomain/slug/postname and still access it by going to sitedomain/postname. I want to be able to do the same but with page names instead of posts. Being able to access both urls, the one with base-slug and without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried external rules, but you can achieve that with an internal rewrite and `pagename`:

```
function wpd_page_rewrite(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^anothername/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_page_rewrite' );
```

For parent/child pages you have to set `pagename` to the parent/child path, `page/pagename`, or you can also use `page_id` and use the page's ID.

EDIT - note that you have to [flush rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/flush_rewrite_rules) after adding new ones. a quick way to do this during testing is to visit the permalinks settings page.

Comment: It didn't work for the external rules, but this answer worked for what I was trying to do. So I'll stick with this one. Thanks!